# Как соединить enum и тип double

Tags: c#

Есть у меня такая конструкция.

```
 private  double x1;

        public enum EnumYesNo_for_ball2 
        { 
            Да = x1=5.0,
            Нет = x1=0.0
        }
```

Естественно что  компилятор ругается, вопрос как подружить именно тип данных double с enum. Enum у меня применяется в форме для выбора Да/нет И нужно именно дабловское значение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тип `double` нельзя использовать в `enum`. 
Добавьте вспомогательный метод получения `double` по значению `enum`.

```
private static double GetDoubleByEnum(EnumYesNo_for_ball2 value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case EnumYesNo_for_ball2.Да: return 5.0;
        case EnumYesNo_for_ball2.Нет: return 0.0;
        default: return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Enum:

```
public enum EnumYesNo_for_ball2
{
    Да,
    Нет
}
```

Использование:

```
x1 = GetDoubleByEnum(EnumYesNo_for_ball2.Да); // x1 = 5.0
```

Comment: Вы не так поняли мне кажется задачу, да про то,что нельзя использовать дабл я знаю, но у меня на форме enum, (у меня выбор критерия да или нет) выбрал я Да, мне нужно чтобы переменная x1 приняла значение нужное. например 0,1

Comment: Ну ок, переписал метод

Comment: Можно сделать расширяющий метод - код чуть красивее будет :) А можно совсем поизвращаться и сделать как я - даже чуть эффективнее выйдет xD

Comment: я за расширяющий метод, элегантнее будет

Comment: я тоже за расширяющий метод

Answer (score 1):

раз уж в enum невозможно засунуть дабл, то можно сделать следующий финт хвостом и заменить энам на структуру:

```
public struct YesNo_for_ball2
{
    public double CurrVal = 0.0; // можно запоминать значение как у нама

    public const double Yes = 5.0;
    public const double No  = 0.0;
}
```

и если нужно что-то куда-то присвоить то:

```
double d = YesNo_for_ball2.Yes;
```

Comment: Увы так тоже не работает.

Comment: проапдейтил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Есть любопытный хак: https://ideone.com/061J9k

```
using System;

enum Smth : long
{
  Yes = 0x4014000000000000,
  No = 0x0,
}

static class SmthExts
{
  public static double Value(this Smth x)
  {
    return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble((long)x);
  }
}

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("0x{0:X}", BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(5));
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(Smth.Yes.Value());
    Console.WriteLine(Smth.No.Value());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Вот тебе дабл {ToDouble(TestEnum.asd1)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Вот тебе дабл {ToDouble(TestEnum.asd5)}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static Double ToDouble(TestEnum testEnum)
        {
            return ((Int32)testEnum)*1.0;
        }
    }

    public enum TestEnum: Int32
    {
        asd1 = 1,
        asd5 = 5,
    }

Вот тебе дабл 1
Вот тебе дабл 5
```

!!! Нужно учесть базовый класс для TestEnum и приведение типа в ToDouble(TestEnum testEnum) что бы не нарваться на выход за пределы мин/макс значений integer